# Error with missing kw parameters in Pytests tmpdir mkdir method

Tags: python, pytest

I have a class `Foo`. Its supposed to persist files in some folder. First it ensures the folder and all its parents exist.

```
class Foo:
    def persist_stuff(self, in_folder: Path):
        in_folder.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) 
        # TODO: persist stuff
```

I test this code with pytest and use the [`tmpdir`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/tmp_path.html#the-tmpdir-and-tmpdir-factory-fixtures) fixture, which helps cleaning up any created files

```
def test_foo(tmpdir):
    foo = Foo()
    foo.create_folder(tmpdir / "foo")
    # TODO: test
```

Unfortunately, calling [`mkdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir) on `tmpdir` with kw parameters raises a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: LocalPath.mkdir() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exist_ok'
```

It seems those newly introduced kw parameters have not been added to pytests implementation of `LocalPath` yet.

There are two trivial solutions which I both don't like:

1. Adapt tests to use my own custom test directory and delete it after every test
2. Rewrite my production code by calling a custom function that does the same job as `mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)` without triggering this issue.

I don't like either solution (especially the second is a no-go). Is there another - maybe a little less crude - way?

Comment: You are calling a different method than you show, but would `foo.create_folder(Path(tmpdir) / "foo")` work?

Comment: that did work indeed! though I just found out that `tmp_path` should be used instead of `tmpdir`, which works

Answer (score 0):

From the [tmpdir and tmpdir_factory fixtures section](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/tmp_path.html#the-tmpdir-and-tmpdir-factory-fixtures):

> ## Note
>
> These days, it is preferred to use tmp_path and tmp_path_factory.
>
> [...]

So, just using `tmp_path` worked. The correct function would therefore be:

```
def test_foo(tmp_path):
    foo = Foo()
    foo.create_folder(tmp_path / "foo")
    # TODO: test
```